# suppressing openGL runtime warnings

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am getting the following warning sporadically in a Win32 console application written in C++ compiled with VC++ 2010 Express:

```
OpenGL Warning: GetRandomRgn returned (-1) instead of (1), VisibleRegions update failed
```

Since this seems to have no adverse effect on the application I will be happy with simply suppressing this warning from showing in the console. Any ideas?

Thanks,
-naor

Comment: OpenGL usually doesn't produce such warnings, do you have any idea where it might come from?

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned this is happening in the "virtual" Win7 window of a VirtualBox guest under Mac OS X host. Nevertheless, the call that fails is a Windows call, but it is clearly intercepted and reported by an openGL method. Since I only wish to suppress the warning and not fix the call, would there be an easy way to do this with openGL settings? Thanks, -n

Answer (score 1):

So this is coming from [virtual box code](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Additions/common/crOpenGL/stub.c).

It's a windows call ([GetRandomRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that fails. The failure reasons are documented in the windows documentation (which I don't fully understand), but in all cases, it's not at all related to OpenGL.

Suppressing the warning would mean modifying the virtualbox code to remove the print, but at that point, you might want to fix the code instead.

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned this happens on a VirtualBox win7. Makes sense since maybe the windows code is confused by the fact that it is running in a window inside a much larger monitor?

Comment: So modifying the VirtualBox code seems rather dangerous. Any chance of a hack workaround? Thanks,